# Insert Form Data into Database

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database

I Created One Custom Module for Price Negotiate. And Put One Custom Button on the "Product View Page" via the "custom.phtml" file. If Button is Clicked then Popup will open and In Popup, There is a Form Fields Like : Firstname, Lastname, etc.
So how can I insert that Form Fields Data into my custom table?

Any Kind of Help will be appreciated.

**Here Is My `IndexController.php` File.**

```
<?php
class Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
    }
    
}
```

And Here Is My Template "pricenegotiate.phtml" file

```
<!--
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
<input type="Button" name="negotiate" value="Negotiate">
<button class="button btn-cart" type="button" title="Negotiate" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Negotiate</button>
</div>
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
    <button class="" style="font-size:20pt;color:black;background-color:sky-blue;border:2px solid #336600;padding:3px" type="button" title="Negotiate" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Negotiate</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Negotiate Price</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="form" action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstname">First Name :</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Enter Number" maxlength="10" min="0" max="9">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="requestedprice">Requested Price:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="requestedprice" placeholder="Enter Your Price" min="0">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="qty">Quantity:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="note">Note:</label>
                  <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="note" placeholder="Enter Note">
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Place Request</button>
            </form>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div> 
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And Table Name Is** `pricenegotiate`.

**My `config.xml` File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <pricenegotiate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate</module>
                    <frontName>pricenegotiate</frontName>
                </args>
            </pricenegotiate>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <pricenegotiate>
                    <file>pricenegotiate.xml</file>
                </pricenegotiate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <pricenegotiate>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate</module>
                    <frontName>pricenegotiate</frontName>
                </args>
            </pricenegotiate>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <pricenegotiate module="pricenegotiate">
                <title>Price Negotiate</title>
                <sort_order>72</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="pricenegotiate">
                        <title>Manage Price Negotiate</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>pricenegotiate/adminhtml_pricenegotiate</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </pricenegotiate>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <pricenegotiate>
                            <title>Price Negotiate Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </pricenegotiate>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <pricenegotiate>
                    <file>pricenegotiate.xml</file>
                </pricenegotiate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <pricenegotiate>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>pricenegotiate_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </pricenegotiate>
            <pricenegotiate_mysql4>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <pricenegotiate>
                        <table>pricenegotiate</table>
                    </pricenegotiate>
                </entities>
            </pricenegotiate_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <pricenegotiate_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </pricenegotiate_setup>
            <pricenegotiate_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>


            </pricenegotiate_write>
            <pricenegotiate_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </pricenegotiate_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <pricenegotiate>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_Block</class>
            </pricenegotiate>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <pricenegotiate>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_Helper</class>
            </pricenegotiate>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: please note your modifying code and table name you created

Comment: @ 3CE : I am Edit the Question

Comment: @H_Parekh provide your config.xml code

Comment: @ Murtuza Zabuawala : I Edit the question and append `config.xml` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <?php
    class Sigmasolve_Pricenegotiate_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->renderLayout();
        }
        public function saveAction(){
              $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
              $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
              $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `telephone`,`request_price`,`quantity`,`note`)
VALUES ('".$data['first_name']."', '".$data['last_name']."', '".$data['email']."', '".$data['telephone']."', '".$data['request_price']."', '".$data['quantity']."', '".$data['note']."')";
$connection->query($query); 
        }
    
    }
```

this is a simple insertion method we just create saveAction

inform just add the action URL of your controller. U can escape the query prevent SQL injection

```
<!--
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
<input type="Button" name="negotiate" value="Negotiate">
<button class="button btn-cart" type="button" title="Negotiate" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Negotiate</button>
</div>
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <button class="" style="font-size:20pt;color:black;background-color:sky-blue;border:2px solid #336600;padding:3px" type="button" title="Negotiate" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Negotiate</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Negotiate Price</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="form" action="<?php Mage::getBaseUrl('') ?>[controller_first_name]/save" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstname">First Name :</label>
                  <input type="text" name='first_name' class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" name= "last_name" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
                  <input type="number" name="telephone" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Enter Number" maxlength="10" min="0" max="9">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="requestedprice">Requested Price:</label>
                  <input type="number" name="request_price" class="form-control" id="requestedprice" placeholder="Enter Your Price" min="0">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="qty">Quantity:</label>
                  <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="note">Note:</label>
                  <input type="textarea" name="note" class="form-control" id="note" placeholder="Enter Note">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Place Request</button>
            </form>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer . But I have Error Like "Invalid Url"

Comment: in form action u put your {baseUrl}/controller_front_name/controllerName/method_saveAcion

Comment: any luck do u understand

Comment: in your config.xml fontName = pricenegotiate so url is {baseUrl}/pricenegotiate/index/save in form action

Comment: Yes I am Exactly wirte above action but i am getting 404 error

Comment: did u clear the cache

Comment: yes clear the cache but getting same

Comment: <form name="form" action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>pricenegotiate/index/save" method="post">

Comment: same written bro

Comment: just inspect element and check the form tag action attribute

Comment: @H_Parekh any luck

Comment: Yes +1 for your answer